# How to define the type of list selecting in Flow.js?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Say I have a function `getSingle()` that accepts an array of objects like this:

```
[{
  value: 'm',
  name: 'Male',
}, {
  value: 'f',
  name: 'Female',
}]
```

After doing the select it only returns the `value` of the selected object (i.e. `m` or `f`) in this case.

I have an enum type `Sex` defined as `'m' | 'f'`

So I would like `getSingle` to return the type `Sex` when given this input value. What is the signature for `getSingle`?

```
getSingle(choices: Array<{
  value: string,
  name: string,
}>): ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need use generic type here -> https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/

So your case with generic type will be:

```
getSingle<T>(choices: Array<{
  value: T,
  name: string,
}>): T
```

It is also possible to specify what type generic type should be, like following:

```
type Sex = 'm'| 'f';

getSingle<T: Sex>(choices: Array<{
  value: T,
  name: string,
}>): T
```

Read more about this case here -> https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-adding-types-to-generics